# Julia - accessing Dict values by name in @variable and @constraint expressions

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I wonder if it possible to access Dict values by name in expressions such is this one:

```
@objective(
    premex,
    Min,
    sum((u["cap"] - PRODAMOUNT[op, u, t]) * u["util_cost1"]
        for op in _ORDER_PRODUCTS, u in UNITS, t in TIME))
```

_ORDER_PRODUCTS:

```
Dict{String,Dict{String,Any}}("o18-p25" => Dict("order" => "o18","value" => 3000.0f0,"product" => "p25"),"o18-p36" => Dict("order" => "o18","value" => 63.0f0,"product" => "p36"),"o23-p39" => Dict("order" => "o23","value" => 204.75f0,"product" => "p39"),"o16-p32" => Dict("order" => "o16","value" => 336.0f0,"product" => "p32"),"o22-p37" => Dict("order" => "o22","value" => 50.0f0,"product" => "p37"),"o1-p5" => Dict("order" => "o1","value" => 60.0f0,"product" => "p5"),"o11-p28" => Dict("order" => "o11","value" =....
```

UNITS:

```
UNITS = Dict(["CINTAS" => Dict(["cap" => 1000, "mincap" => 50, "dcap" => 24830, "util_cost1" => 1000, "maxprodr" => 24830]), "BUHLER1" => Dict(["cap" => 1500, "mincap" => 60, "dcap" => 37245, "util_cost1" => 1000, "maxprodr" => 37245]), ...
```

When I run this I got an error:

ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Pair{String,Dict{String,Integer}}, ::String)

And when I substitute u["cap"] to a number it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself (...):

```
    @variable(premex, PRODAMOUNT[op in keys(_ORDER_PRODUCTS), u in keys(UNITS), t in TIME])

    @objective(
        premex,
        Min,
        sum((u["cap"] - PRODAMOUNT[key1, key2, t]) * u["util_cost1"]
            for (key1, op) in _ORDER_PRODUCTS, (key2, u) in UNITS, t in TIME
                ))
```

there are 3 factors to take care of:

1. can't index variable with dictionary object, so it has to be Int or String
2. this is the way to iterate through Dict: for (key1, op) in _ORDER_PRODUCTS
3. and this is the way to get only keys for indexing variables: op in keys(_ORDER_PRODUCTS)

Comment: If you solved it you should accept your own answer.

Comment: @MatějRačinský thanks, I would accept it immediately, but as you know already = it is not possible, thus I left it for later, and as you know already = after I forgot about it :)